# How to trigger CSS animation once user change the slide?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

i am using [Animate](https://animate.style/) for my slides content. i want to applay the css transtion everytime when the user goes back and furth. however my fist slide has the transtions i want but the problem is that they load all at same time. i need some sort of js funtction to envoke the transtion once the slide chnages not before.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far, in `code snippet` , (`Ctrl + M`) shortcut in editor.

Comment: just figure it out but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out by adding a simple .active class to a slide and then showing the CSS transition only once it is active.
Now both my images and H1 are animated once the slide is moved.

```css
/* ---------- CSS TRANSACTIONS ------------ */

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
            transform: translateX(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}






@keyframes slide-in-bottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}





.slide-active h1{
  animation: slide-in-left 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.7s both;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-left 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.7s both;
}

.slide-active img{
  animation: slide-in-bottom 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s both;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-bottom 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s both;
}
```